# session is not working with angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, session

Hi I'm new to angularJS and PHP,

I'm trying to maintain session between two pages and the code as follows,

Index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["id"])) {    
        $post_date = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
        $data = json_decode($post_date,true);
        $nme = $data['name'];
        $passwd= $data['password'];
        if (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin_auth` WHERE `username` = '$nme' and `password` = '$passwd' ")) { 
            $_session["id"] = $nme;
            echo $_session["id"];
            return;
        } else {
            echo "invalid user";
        }
    }
?>
```

and I'm checking the session as follows

exe.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header("Location:index.php");
}
    echo "SESSION set";
?>
```

It will always redirect me to the index page even when the session is set in index page. Index.php printing out correct value

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You also appear to be storing password in Plain Text. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: You should probably show us the javascript code that send the data to `index.php`

Comment: `echo $_session["id"];` this statement is printing value that means the values coming from java script..  right?